# Rigetti "Timeout on client tcp://127.0.0.1:5555, method name quil_to_native_quil" error

Tags: qiskit, compiling, rigetti

I am trying to run a relatively large quantum circuit on Rigetti's Aspen-11. I have a reservation for later today, but I am getting an error when running the code. I know that if you use:

```
from pyquil import *
from pyquil.gates import *
from qiskit_rigetti import RigettiQCSProvider
```

and,

```
provider = RigettiQCSProvider()
backend = provider.get_backend(name = "Aspen-11")
```

the line of code:

```
job = execute(qc, backend)
```

where qc is my quantum circuit, should work. However, I am getting an error that says "Timeout on client tcp://127.0.0.1:5555, method name quil_to_native_quil"
I am using Qiskit, and have tried switching the code to PyQuil as well and nothing changed. Is there a chance my code is just too large? It works fine on the IBMQ QASM simulator (3 seconds run time), but for some reason it will not compile for Rigetti's system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems indeed [related with the size of circuit](https://github.com/rigetti/pyquil/issues/935#issuecomment-507697597). If I interpret [`qiskit_rigetti.RigettiQCSProvider` documentation](https://qiskit-rigetti.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/index.html#qiskit_rigetti.RigettiQCSProvider) correctly, you should be able to extend the timeout in the following way:

```
provider = RigettiQCSProvider(execution_timeout=60)
backend = provider.get_backend(name = "Aspen-11")
```